# Can I tag a file from Quick Look?

Tags: quicklook, finder-tag

I'd be able to very quickly tag a bunch of photos for later processing.

Comment: I assigned a keyboard shortcut to "Tags..." from the File menu in Finder. I can hit the shortcut while in Quick View to tag the file quickly. It also works for multi-file tagging, so you can tag multiple files at once. Let me know if this does what you need. I can provide steps on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tags feature in Finder<sup>1</sup> already has a keyboard shortcut which can be activated whilst in Quick Look. **Press ⌘⇧T to set a tag** on the currently selected file.

---

To set a custom shortcut…

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **App Shortcuts**.
2. Click the **+** button to add a new shortcut.
3. Set the **Application** to **Finder.app**, and the **Menu Title** to **Tags…**.
4. Set your keyboard shortcut and press **Add**.

<sup><sup>1</sup> As this is a feature of Finder, not Quick Look, the modal popup may be behind the Quick Look window.</sup>

Comment: That did it, thanks, especially since Quick Look remembers its screen position, so placing it off to the side ensures it doesn't obstruct the tagging window in Finder.

Comment: I don't think this works in 2024